# Need to round-off value of a field

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a report, I need to round-off value.

If the value of the field is 1.10, then after round-off it should be 2.00.

I have used `Round` function (`round({Table.field})`) but it's using midpoint round off, when value goes greater or equal to 1.5 then it's getting round-off to 2.00.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using round, use ceiling.

```
var aNumber = 1.1;
var roundedUp = Math.Ceiling(aNumber);
// roundedUp == 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply #Ken, This work in C# code but how do use this same thing in crystal report? Could you give me any crystal report formula?

Comment: If you do not have access to a ceiling function then I think you could force the math to always round up by adding 0.5 to the value you are rounding. `round({Table.field} + 0.5)`

Comment: Actually that is a terrible idea. Any int value would go up by one when rounded. Let me think of a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, please #Ken.

Comment: Does the version of CR you are using have the truncate function? If so you could `if remainder({table.field},1) <> 0 then truncate({table.field})+1 else {table.field}`. I am not so sure on the syntax because I do not have CR handy.

Comment: Thanks #Ken, I have not used truncate function before. Let me try this.

Comment: The truncate function should cut off the decimal portion of the value (truncate(2.4) returns 2) so that you can then just add one. You will just need to check that the value isn't already a whole number so that you don't turn something like 3.0 into 4 on accident.

Comment: I have just executed your code and I got perfect solution, a ton of thanks #Ken. You saved my lots of time.